# ¿Como puedo mandar un archivo PDF generado con DOMPDF usando PHPMAILER?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buenas tardes.

Tengo un problema, y es que quiero mandar por correo electrónico un archivo pdf generado con `DOMPDF` utilizando la librería `PHPMAILER`; el archivo pdf se genera de manera correcta así como la función para mandar correos electrónicos.

Tengo dos archivos, en uno está todo lo que hace `PHPMAILER` (junto con más código) y en otro archivo tengo la platilla que genera el archivo pdf
¿Como puedo realizar ésta operación de mandar el archivo pdf por correo eléctrónico?

De antemano agradezco su apoyo.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno sabiendo, que el archivo PDF se genera de forma normal, sin problemas, y que además el correo se envia sin inconvenientes, no queda nada más que agregar el archivo PDF generado, que me imagino que debe estar en tu servidor local.

Siendo así, prueba lo siguiente:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . 'tu_carpeta/pdf/file.pdf', 'nombre_alternativo.pdf');
```

Espero te pueda servir.

Saludos,

Comment: Lo agregaré, gracias; una pregunta adicional, el botón que envía el correo es el mismo que crea el archivo PDF y ese archivo es el mismo que necesito enviar, pero manda el mail vacio, no se si se pueda agregar un retardo al momento de enviar el archivo y que se pueda descargar el archivo sin pedir la confirmación del usuario.

Comment: Ah, buen detalle. En ese caso, el path del archivo, debe ser el temporal donde esta el archivo PDF, pero no estoy 100% seguro que lo agregue de todas formas al enviar el correo, debería, pero no lo he probado. Una vez que el archivo este creado, envias el correo (en el mismo script)

Answer (score 0):

Después de leer tu pregunta y de leer los comentarios, lo que yo haría sería:

Primero generar el PDF y a la hora de guardar el PDF, usar esta intrucción `file_put_contents($path, $dompdf->output())`

Con esta instrucción lo que vas a hacer es guardar el PDF, en la ruta de tu servidor que le quieras decir.

Luego podrás enviar el mail, sabiendo la dirección con la instrucción

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $path, 'nombre_alternativo.pdf');
```

Para evitar que se envie el correo antes de generar el PDF, intenta sacar el envio a un fichero externos o a una función de manera que una vez generado el PDF y guardado llames a esta función o hagas un redirect a la nueva página pasando la ruta del PDF